# Exlude layout in xml preview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've got a RecyclerView in my layout, nothing strange.
The problem rises when I'm working on the layout and the recycler view's preview occupies all the screen. 
Is it possible to **exclude a layout** (in this case the Recycler's one) **from the preview** ?

Thx anticipately !

Answer (score 5):

You can set `tools:visibility="gone"`. To use it, you have to add the following URI namespace to your root layout

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Tools only apply in `XML` preview.

From the [doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes)

> Android has a dedicated XML namespace intended for tools to be able to
>   record information in XML files, and have that information stripped
>   when the application is packaged such that there is no runtime or
>   download size penalty

Comment: Thx for your help, but I've tried to do so and nothing happened. 
Have I some wrong settings for the preview ?

Comment: Show us your layout's XML.